# Makefile dependency being ignored

Tags: c, makefile

I created a simple makefile to understand the basic idea behind how they work and it's not performing the way I expected. Please see the following:

```
test:  test.c
    gcc -o test test.c
```

My understanding is this should only run when there have been changes to the test.c file. The problem is it runs every time regardless of whether or not there were changes.

I've noticed that this occurs when I use arbitrary target names. If I make the target name an actual file name such as "test.exe", it works correctly, but all the tutorials I've seen show dependencies working with arbitrary target names. Any idea as to why this is occurring?

Comment: That should work. Can you confirm the second line begins with a tab and not four spaces?

Comment: If the target and the output file name match then it should work with any name. Can you show the `make` output exactly? As well as the `make -rRd` output?

Comment: @abligh The second line does indeed begin with a tab and not four spaces.

Comment: @EtanReisner The output is always "gcc -o test test.c" when I type "make test" in the CLI.

Comment: Is the timestamp on `test.c` in the future?

Comment: @EtanReisner I'm not sure I understand what you mean by a "future timestamp". Could you elaborate?

Comment: @user2154633 : Tried the same on my PC. For the first time `gcc -o test test.c` is called, but after that with no change in the `test or test.c` file I get `make: "test" is up to date.`

Comment: @SantoshA What version of gcc are using? I have MinGW and its corresponding make utility.

Comment: @user2154633: Version of `GCC` is `"gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313"` and `Make` is `"GNU Make 3.81"`.

Comment: You are on windows. The output executable is therefore called _test.exe_. Not sure how mingw deals with this (I'm only familiar with cygwin _make_). Run _make_ with the `-d` flag to see what is happening (look for a message like `target file "test" does not exist`). If you also use the `-Rr` flags at the same time, the debug output will be considerably shorter.

Comment: @bobbogo He is giving an explicit `-o test` argument. That should generate a `test` binary even on Windows I would think. If not then yes that is likely the problem.

Comment: I mean what does `ls -l test.c` say? Does it have a timestamp in the future? If it does then make will always see that as being newer than the built `test` binary.

Comment: @Etan The resulting executable file will _still_ have a `.exe` suffix on Windows, even though the name given to the `-o` option did not.

Comment: If @bobbogo is correct and `gcc -o test test.c` creates a `test.exe` binary file then that is odd, unfortunate and annoying. But does explain the issue. In which case the solution is to use `test.exe:` and `gcc -o '$@' test.c` or even better `gcc -o '$@' $^` or (possibly) better still not to have a rule for this at all and use the builtin rule for this job.

Comment: @bobbogo I ran make with the -d and -Rr flags and sure enough, the issue was that make doesn't recognize the 'test' target because it's missing the .exe extension. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Windows, Make automatically adds the suffix `.exe` to the generated program.

Since the name of the target is different from the result of the rule, Make tries to generate it again.

You should write your makefile like this:

```
EXE := test.exe

$(EXE): test.c
    gcc -o $@ $^
```

If you need portability and don't want to rewrite the rule, use this:

```
EXE := test

if ($(OS),Windows_NT)
EXE := $(EXE).exe
endif

$(EXE): test.c
    gcc -o $@ $^
```

Comment: For portability just use cygwin make. Cygwin sorts out this sort of mess in a (fairly) reasonable way.

Comment: Last time I saw someone use the newest version of Cygwin make, he couldn't run a not so complicated Makefile … switching to MinGW make did work, so I stick to it since then.